# Set value to undefined variable

Tags: perl

I'm trying to set default values to some variables. I know how to do it but I would like to do this task using a subroutine and I'm having problems.

I have this three variables: `$t, $insize, $libtype.`
And this is the simple function to set default values to them if they're undefined:

```
sub SetUnlessDefined {
   my $t = 1 if !( defined $t );
   my $insize = 300 if !( defined $insize );
   my $libtype = 0 if !( defined $libtype );
   return( $t, $insize, $libtype );
}
```

I execute the function like this:

```
( $t, $insize, $libtype ) = SetUnlessDefined( $t, $insize, $libtype );
```

If all my variables are undefined the function runs OK, but if I have a value for any of them its not working.

Anyone can suggest me a solution? Or a correct way to check if a variables are defined and if they not set a value?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't read the parameters in the subroutine body:

```
sub defaults {
    my ($t, $insize, $libtype) = @_;    # <--- HERE
    $t = 1 unless defined $t;
    $insize = 300 unless defined $insize;
    $libtype = 0 unless defined $libtype;
    return ($t, $insize, $libtype);
}
```

There are other ways how to approach the task, though:

```
sub defaults {
    my @defaults = (1, 300, 0);
    for my $i (0 .. $#defaults) {
        $_[$i] //= $defaults[$i];  # Perl 5.10 needed
    }
}
```

No assignment is needed in the subroutine call anymore, as the arguments are aliased to the members of @_:

```
defaults($t, $insize, $libtype);
```

Comment: Oh God... stupid mistake, to many hours in front of the computer. Thanks @choroba.

Answer (score 0):

The `my $t` part of the code is always running, so in the case where global `$t` is defined, the local `$t` is instantiated as undefined, and is returned.

A solution is to use something like this

```
if (! defined $t ) {
    my $t = 1 ;
}
```

Or maybe just

```
if (! defined $t ) {
    $t = 1 ;
}
```

and don't return anything.

You are also sending parameters to the function, which are being ignored... maybe the whole thing could be redone without the parameters, and without the second assignment, like this

```
sub SetUnlessDefined {
   if (! defined $t ) {
       $t = 1 ;
   }
   if (! defined $insize ) {
       $insize = 3000;
   }
   if (! defined $libtype ) {
       $libtype = 0;
   }
}


SetUnlessDefined();
```